# Is there any way to skip fatal error from include file in php?

Tags: php, fatal-error

If I include a file in to php. If there is any fatal error in that php then is there any way to skip that .

```
<?php
   include "somefile.php";
   echo "OK"; // Is there any way to print this OK  If there is any fatal error on somefile.php
?>
```

> I need to include this somefile.php file. It may return fatal error
>   for some host. I want to skip this file for those host.

Please Advice me.

Comment: I need to include that file sometimes it may return fatal error for some host.

Comment: use the `require` instead of include.

Comment: "it may return fatal error for some host" - what kind of fatal? Why exactly does it occur?

Comment: PS: is there any chance to use `php -l file.php` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this, you can define your own continuation function that will take over in case of a fatal error. This uses [`register_shutdown_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) to intercept the fatal error.

Usage:

```
function my_continuation_func($filename, $arg2) {
    // On fatal error during include, continue script execution from here.
    // When this function ends, or if another fatal error occurs,
    // the execution will stop.
}

include_try('my_continuation_func', array($filename, $arg2));
$data = include($filename);
$error = include_catch();
```

If a fatal error occurs (like a parse error), script execution will continue from `my_continuation_func()`. Otherwise, `include_catch()` returns `true` if there was an error during parsing.

Any output (like `echo 'something';`) from the `include()` is treated as an error. Unless you enabled output by passing `true` as the third argument to `include_try()`.

This code automatically takes care of possible working directory changes in the shutdown function.

**You can use this for any number of includes, but the second fatal error that occurs cannot be intercepted: the execution will stop.**

Functions to be included:

```
function include_try($cont_func, $cont_param_arr, $output = false) {
    // Setup shutdown function:
    static $run = 0;
    if($run++ === 0) register_shutdown_function('include_shutdown_handler');

    // If output is not allowed, capture it:
    if(!$output) ob_start();
    // Reset error_get_last():
    @user_error('error_get_last mark');
    // Enable shutdown handler and store parameters:
    $params = array($cont_func, $cont_param_arr, $output, getcwd())
    $GLOBALS['_include_shutdown_handler'] = $params;
}

function include_catch() {
    $error_get_last = error_get_last();
    $output = $GLOBALS['_include_shutdown_handler'][2];
    // Disable shutdown handler:
    $GLOBALS['_include_shutdown_handler'] = NULL;
    // Check unauthorized outputs or if an error occured:
    return ($output ? false : ob_get_clean() !== '')
        || $error_get_last['message'] !== 'error_get_last mark';
}

function include_shutdown_handler() {
    $func = $GLOBALS['_include_shutdown_handler'];
    if($func !== NULL) {
        // Cleanup:
        include_catch();
        // Fix potentially wrong working directory:
        chdir($func[3]);
        // Call continuation function:
        call_user_func_array($func[0], $func[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fatal means fatal ...
There is no way to recover from a fatal error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.register-shutdown-function.php).

```
<?php
function echoOk()
    {
    echo "OK";
    }

register_shutdown_function(function ()
        {
        $error = error_get_last();
        // to make sure that there is any fatal error
        if (isset($error) &&
            ($error['type'] == E_ERROR
            || $error['type'] == E_PARSE
            || $error['type'] == E_COMPILE_ERROR
            || $error['type'] == E_CORE_ERROR))
            {
            echoOk();
            }
        });

include "somefile.php";

echoOk();
```

But you can do it only once. Any further fatal error will stop execution.

Answer (score 1):

PHP won't tolerate with Fatal Errors. Best to check the included file and solve it.
Actually, you can try looking at [register-shutdown-function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php), but it's not recommended to run away from your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. It can be done through a simple if statement

You Have:

```
<?php
   include "somefile.php";
   echo "OK"; // Is there any way to print this OK  If there is any fatal error on
?>
```

Try This:

```
<?php
   if(include "somefile.php"){
          // echo do something if success
   }else{
          echo "OK";
   }
```

Comment: This does not work if somefile.php contains `<?php $str = '` (partial written cache file).

Answer (score 0):

**edit: I missed the word fatal.** As stated, you can't recover from a fatal error. If it is just an exception the hastly writen response below will work.

Including another php module is the same as that code being inserted inline, so a simple `try-catch` statement should work:

```
<?php
    try {
        include "somefile.php";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
    echo "OK"; 
 ?>
```

Comment: Won't work for fatal errors ... only exceptions and there is no way to throw an exception on a fatal error.

Comment: Yeah, I must have glossed over that. These comments are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a **set_error_handler**() function that doesn't die on fatal errors, but instead Apache crashed. In other words, PHP needs to die so that the system doesn't.

See this [**LINK**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php)

Answer (score 0):

Fatal Error means there is something seriously wrong with the including code. As @Orangepill said there is no way to stop this fatal error message popping up. Please go through your coding and find the error.