# Include file error in php

Tags: php

I have a simple problem with php. I want to include a simple PHP file. I am using `include("filename.php")`  to include the file.

But the problem is that, if the file inclusion is OK then it shows the error but if is there any error in the included file then it simply dies and there is no further execution.

I want that if there is any error in the included file, it simply shows the error and further execution should continue :

Like after the include file, I am showing `footer`. currently if there is any error in the code then footer is not showing, if I want to show the footer if include file has error. How can I do this ?

**Edit** :

```
<?php

include("header.php");
include("dbconnect.php");

<div class="content">
    <div class="container">
    <div >
    <form name="savecode" action="" method="post">
<div class="span12">

<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="language" value="PHP">
<textarea id="code" name="yourcode" style="width:800px;height:200px;"><?php echo $code;?></textarea>
<br/><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="reruncode" value ="Run the code">
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="span12">
<h5>Output of the above code</h5>

<textarea id="output" style="width:800px;height:200px;" disabled="disabled">
<?php

include("testfile.php");
?>
</textarea>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
$uniquid = md5(uniqid($email,true));
echo "<input type='hidden' id='uniqid' value=$uniquid>";
?>
<input type="hidden" id="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>">
<br/><input id="submit" value="Save this code" class="btn btn-primary" />
<?php
}
?>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

include("footer.php");
```

Comment: show us your inclusion file code

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/17160851/1503018

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible if there is a parse error in the included file, the execution terminates. Try and catching the exception will also not work. Its discussed further [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41810)  
If it is a general error in the included file, make sure that you try catch all possible exceptions in the included file so that it fails gracefully and then in that case it can be included.

Comment: There is one way to 'catch' fatal errors in included files http://stackoverflow.com/a/17160996/1503018

Comment: That seems to be more of a custom handler if there is a shutdown, if you want to clean up stuff. There is no way to continue execution after that right?

Comment: yes, yes. But you could consider this way when you trying to do ^that staff.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put your HTML in a string or close the PHP tags before HTML start and again start the PHP tags after HTML ends.

In your code you missed it. Another is Form with in Form element. It will not work when you post the data. Your Form tag is not closed anywhere in the code.

e.g.

```
<?php

include("header.php");
include("dbconnect.php");

?>

<div class="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <form name="savecode" action="" method="post">
               <div class="span12">

                   <form action="#" method="post">
                       <input type="hidden" name="language" value="PHP">
                       <textarea id="code" name="yourcode" style="width:800px;height:200px;"><?php echo $code;?></textarea>
                       <br/><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="reruncode" value ="Run the code">
               </div>
               <hr/>
               <div class="span12">
                    <h5>Output of the above code</h5>

                     <textarea id="output" style="width:800px;height:200px;" disabled="disabled">
                     <?php include("testfile.php"); ?>
                     </textarea>
                     <?php
                     if(isset($_SESSION['email']))
                     {
                         $uniquid = md5(uniqid($email,true));
                         echo "<input type='hidden' id='uniqid' value=$uniquid>";
                     ?>
                         <input type="hidden" id="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>">
                         <br/><input id="submit" value="Save this code" class="btn btn-primary" />
                     <?php
                     }
                     ?>
                </div>
           </div>
       </div>

    </div>
</div>

<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: I have solved this error but this did not resolved my problem of file include

Comment: post your error that you are getting. enable the error reporting by **init('display_errors', 1)** and **error_reporting(E_ALL)**

Comment: are you getting my question or giving answer on fly ... I am getting errors but I want to execute the code if error occurs in file execution

Comment: then you need to use **try catch block** as @sectus pointed in the below comments.